# Julia: circular reference

Tags: julia

how can is solve this problem?

```
mutable struct Parent
    name::String
    children::Vector{Child}

    function Parent(name)
        return new(name)

    end

end

mutable struct Child
    name::String
    parent::Parent

    function Child(name)
        return new(name)

    end

end

parent = Parent("father")
child = Child("son")
```

Produces an error

> LoadError: UndefVarError: Child not defined

Is there some way to handle this case?

Comment: Mutually recursive types are still an [open issue] in the language.

Comment: ([missing link](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/269#issuecomment-441829356))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to handle this currently is via a parametric type (I know it is not perfect). Here is an example which additionally restricts the parameter so that you get almost what you want:

```
abstract type AbstractChild end

mutable struct Parent{T<:AbstractChild}
    name::String
    children::Vector{T}
    function Parent{T}(name) where {T<:AbstractChild}
        return new{T}(name)
    end

end

mutable struct Child <: AbstractChild
    name::String
    parent::Parent

    function Child(name)
        return new(name)
    end
end

Parent(name) = Parent{Child}(name)

parent = Parent("father")
child = Child("son")
```

Comment: Presumably you would also want to instantiate the `child` with the `parent` you just created: `child = Child("son", parent)` and then add the `child` to `parent.children` with `push!(parent.children, child)`.

Answer (score 0):

And just to add on to @Bogumił Kamiński's answer the abstract type AbstractChild end creates a node for julia to traverse from at runtime in the program.

Comment: This should be a comment to Bogumil's answer, instead of a seperate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the abstract type seems to be the intended use for situations with circularity.

```
abstract type AbstractChild end

mutable struct Parent <: AbstractChild
    name::String
    children::Vector{AbstractChild}
    
    Parent(name) = new(name, Vector{AbstractChild}())
end

mutable struct Child <: AbstractChild
    name::String
    parents::Tuple{AbstractChild, AbstractChild}

    Child(name) = new(name)
end

link(parent1::Parent, parent2::Parent, child::Child) = (
    push!(parent1.children, child);
    push!(parent2.children, child);
    child.parents = (parent1, parent2)
)

father = Parent("father")
mother = Parent("mother")
child = Child("son")

link(father, mother, child)
```

Running the code & inspecting the structures produces the following output (Juila 1.9.4):

```
julia> father
Parent("father", AbstractChild[Child("son", (Parent(#= circular reference @-4 =#), Parent("mother", AbstractChild[Child(#= circular reference @-4 =#)])))])

julia> mother
Parent("mother", AbstractChild[Child("son", (Parent("father", AbstractChild[Child(#= circular reference @-4 =#)]), Parent(#= circular reference @-4 =#)))])

julia> child
Child("son", (Parent("father", AbstractChild[Child(#= circular reference @-4 =#)]), Parent("mother", AbstractChild[Child(#= circular reference @-4 =#)])))
```

According to [[link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/are-circular-references-problematic/93767)], `#= circular reference @-4 =#` is a good sign that we have setup the two-way reference properly.